# VBA For Changing 2 to a Superscript when it's in a defined string

Tags: excel, vba, superscript, dataformat

so I tried to create a code just to do some basic formatting in the headers of long data sets. I have a fixsymbol code to change the um to micrometers with the proper symbol but when I try to run the code below to change the (um2) to a superscript 2 it flashes Error 13 type mismatch and the debug highlights this line "Position = InStr(c.Value, "µm2")" It still runs the code but spits the error at the end and if I try to run it on a raw data set not in a table it crashes Excel. How would I fix this error so I can have it run as a part of a larger script without crashing?

```
Sub ChangeToSuperScript()
Dim X As Long
Dim Position As Long
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A:Z") 'range of cells
Position = InStr(c.Value, "µm2") 'change the number 2 into a potentiation sign
If Position Then c.Characters(Position + 2, 1).Font.Superscript = True
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're iterating over every single cell in columns A - Z... that's about 27.3 million cells. Maybe [find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) first.

Comment: Try to replace `c.Value` with `c.Text` in `InStr(c.Value, "µm2")`

Comment: If c contains an error value you may see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can screen out error values.

EDIT: updated to use `SpecialCells` to only operate on fixed values...

```vb
Sub ChangeToSuperScript()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim Position As Long, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no constants
    Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no fixed values
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Position = InStr(c.Value, "µm2")
        Debug.Print c.Address, c.Value, Position
        If Position > 0 Then
            c.Characters(Position + 2, 1).Font.Superscript = True
        End If
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    Debug.Print "Error:" & Err.Description
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, so for this code I am using it on a wide variety of data sizes and each sheet is named depending on a treatment group so it is also dynamic. What would you  suggest for the range to keep it dynamic in cases of data that's 5 columns long to 100 columns long?

Comment: See edit above - `SpecialCells` does a lot of the checking so makes the code simpler

Comment: Hi again, using the above I still get the same error of a Type Mismatch at the ''' If InStr(c.Value, "µm2") > 0 Then''' It runs but it puts the regular letter u as a subscript and doesn't touch the two.

Comment: Sorry - I made a mess of that by editing it after copying it over.  Should be OK now

Comment: I am so sorry to bother again but excel keeps spitting the type mismatch on the line If InStr(c.Value,"µm2") > 0 Then' and it says error code 2042. The issue lies with the C.Value and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: What is the value of `c` when it fails?  What's in that cell ?

Comment: I can't see, it crashes part of the time but it does change the cells needed but where could I find the value where it fails?

Comment: If Excel is actually crashing then something more serious is going on.  If it's not crashing completely then try running the code above and review the Immediate pane in the VB editor afterwards.

Comment: It produces no value for c, says 0 for position, and the immediate pane ends at C 31 which has the word mode with the cell to its right containing #N/A. It's ending in the first data statistics using the Excel Add-In right before the #N/A

Comment: OK we can try suspending calculation while we make the changes - see edit.

Comment: Stops running before the debug print, provides the same error at the same line with the type mismatch at the position=InStr line

Comment: Looks like i forgot to post the updated code.  If this doesn't fix it then you'll need to share a workbook which replicates the issue - upload to google drive/onedrive/box/etc and share a link.